# How to extract files from Plesk backup under Windows?

Tags: backup, plesk

- I created a backup file in Plesk
  panel, downloaded it.
- Renamed file to .zip and uncompressed with WinRar.
- Opened unzipped file in Thunderbird
  email client and extracted
  "site.httpdocs" file.

How do I extract actual files from it? It seems like it is some sort of text document with all files dumped together.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a tool for this here http://andymdn.com/2010/10/11/pleskdump-a-plesk-backup-extraction-utility/. Hopefully it helps you.

Comment: I don't work with plesk anymore (thankfully), but I'm sure it will be helpful to many. Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score -1):

Sooo Simple.

Download the file as per **[click here.](https://manage.grabweb.in/knowledgebase/110/How-to-Download-Backup-Files-from-Server-in-Plesk-10.html)**
WinRar is must installed on your computer.

Righ Click on file click Press E
after that all files extracted in folder as same name of file.

NO need to rename any file which is belong to Plesk backup file.